# Detect android webview URL location change

Tags: android, webview, cordova

Does anyone else know how to track a sort of webview "onLocationChange"? iOS has something like this for its webview.

PS - I am trying to see if I can use the phonegap childbrowser plugin on android to do facebook auth. I'm giving up and just using a facebook plugin I found that uses part of the FB android SDK, but I'd still like to know what's possible.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to manipulate the URL then override this:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url)
```

> Give the host application a chance to
>   take over the control when a new url
>   is about to be loaded in the current
>   WebView.

[[WebViewClient Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html)]