# Tracking browser

Tags: android, youtube, android-service, browser-history

For an in-house application for some client we need to implement a background service that keeps track of websites visited with the browser and YouTube videos that are watched, and reports the data back to a web service. Is there a specific API that captures URLs and videos on the fly and reports to the web service, or does our application need to periodically read and parse the browsing history?

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Do you need to track network access from within your app only our any traffic on the mobile device? I haven't used this VpnService but might be what you are looking for: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html if you're interested on tracking url's within your app check the WebView docs or other questions her such as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192314/detect-android-webview-url-location-change

Comment: I didn't quite get what you asked, but imagine a background service that keeps track of visited sites and watched videos and send the data to a web service, that runs without any user interaction in the background.

Comment: Right, but any sites using any browser or just sites viewed using your in-house application?

Comment: Any web site. We solved it with a background service that periodically goes through the browsing history.