# Java - WebView What event handles (watches) URL changes - Android

Tags: java, android, webview

The app does a login to a web application using `WebView`. Once in the webview, the webview appears to handle everything for you as it should based on the user's clicks. However I need to review on each event if the URL changes to a specific logout URL.

How can I return the user to the app itself when the user logs out on the web application within the webview? I do not want the webview to stay as the active view.

I have tried WebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading and View.OnTouchListsner.

The class I tried to implement public but it didn't allow me.

```
class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
        {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);


            }
        }
```

Here's the code before I want to call the method to check the URL;

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final EditText phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone1);
        final EditText login = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
        final EditText pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        phone.requestFocus();
        final Context context = this;
        submit  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
        sbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loginCred);
        chcred = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cBox);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textstring(phone, login, pass);
                encPhone = URLEncoder.encode(Phone);
                encLogin = URLEncoder.encode(Login);
                encPass = URLEncoder.encode(Pass);

                if (chcred.isChecked()) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    prefwrite(editor);
                }
                pushurl();
                clear(phone, login, pass);
            }
        });

        WebViewClient() //Right here is where I want to call it
```

Comment: does the answer on this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192314/detect-android-webview-url-location-change

Comment: Thank you all for answering. Here's the issues I'm having following the advice from Jorge. I impmented a class called myWebClient Extends WebViewClient which includes the onPageStarted method as noted in the first answer. 1.) Although I put this within the OnCreate Instace Android Studio gave me an error saying it can't be a public class so I removed the public and just kept the class. Now I want to use this method but don't know how to access it in the class. I edited my initial response above with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can help you:
[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageStarted(android.webkit.WebView, java.lang.String, android.graphics.Bitmap)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageStarted)

The event does not notify you when the url changes, but does when the page starts to load, at that point you only need to verify the current url.

Answer (score 1):

Try This
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

```
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url) {

                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                    if (uri.getScheme().contains("google") || uri.getScheme().contains("tel")) {
                        try {

                            Intent intent = Intent.parseUri(url, Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME);
                            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
                                startActivity(intent);
                            return true;
                        } catch (URISyntaxException use) {
                            Log.e("TAG", use.getMessage());
                        }
                    } else {
                        webview.loadUrl(url);
                        Log.e("url", url);
                    }

                    return true;
                }

               @Override
               public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                   super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
               }

               @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                }

               @Override
               public void doUpdateVisitedHistory(WebView view, String url, boolean isReload) {
                   super.doUpdateVisitedHistory(view, url, isReload);
                   String currentUrl=view.getUrl();
                  

               }
           });
           webView.loadUrl(url);
```

---

here webView is my WebView and url is the url which  I am using in my webview.

If you want to make some changes with the change in url,then go for

@Override
public void doUpdateVisitedHistory(WebView view, String url, boolean isReload) {
super.doUpdateVisitedHistory(view, url, isReload);
**String currentUrl=view.getUrl();**

```
               }
```

you will get the url updation in this call.