# Save webview's session after destroying the activity on Android

Tags: android, session, webview

I'm developing an Android app where I'm using a webview in an activity. after pressing on a button I destroy this activity to go to another one which contains unity player. How can I open a session on the webview, save the data when I navigate to the unity's activity and then get it back when I come back to the webview's activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If website is creating session, you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15802783/2746389) to get session and [save it to Shared Preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23024962/2746389). Otherwise you can [keep track of page changes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5192554/2746389), and use SharedPreferences to save/retrieve latest page.

Comment: Got it !
Thanks for your help