# Singleton Fragment or save web view state

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, webview, savestate

Here what i want is i have a fragment inside an Activity and it has a web view which is basically chat to customer service. This activity will be started from a button in another activity,

Now the tricky part is i want to save the current session of the web view so that whenever user comes to this activity or whenever i use this fragment i can show the last conversation as well.

So what i have tried is

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // Saving the last loaded url in shared pref and then loading the same url in oncreateview
        return true;
    }
}
```

But when user is having a conversation it is not loading different url thus shouldOverrideUrlLoading is never called.

Help will be highly appriciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As  Al-Amin said i could have saved some keys in my URL but i had no support for this project from back end team as this module is used at many other places so they couldn't change anything so I solved this by using launch mode for my activity as single Instance

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

and for the on back press

```
moveTaskToBack(true);
```

Thus my activity with the webview is not destroyed until i call finish the activity.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this snippet of Code -**

```
public class Tab2Fragment extends Fragment {

    private WebView webView;
    private Bundle webViewBundle;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2,
        container, false);

    webView = (WebView) ll.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    if (webViewBundle == null) {
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.lucazanini.eu");
    } else {
        webView.restoreState(webViewBundle);
    }

    return ll;

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    webViewBundle = new Bundle();
    webView.saveState(webViewBundle);
    }
}
```

**Or Try using this way -**

If website is starting session,then you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15802783/2746389) to get session and [save it to Shared Preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23024962/2746389). Otherwise you can [keep track of page changes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5192554/2746389), and use SharedPreferences to save/retrieve latest page.

Comment: I already tried the above example and it doesnt work :( and for other options you mentioned to save cookies and keep track of page changes i am not getting any callback for the page change as there is no change in the url or it doesnt open a new url its simply a chat screen where user is chatting with customer care.

Comment: https://www.codexpedia.com/android/javascript-interface-for-android-and-javascript-communication/  check this url hope it will help you.

Comment: It is calling some function using java-script, What i need is a way to save this fragment/Web view state and whenever this fragment show this fragment/web view from the saved state not from the beginning Just like a singleton class

Comment: You may keep some params in your url to save state.